# Placing WCF service in folder throws 404

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF and have got stuck with following issue.

I have a WCF service with `webHttpBinding` and hosted on IIS. My project type is WCF application. A service file `Test.svc` is in root folder.

I can access this from the link `http://localhost/WOFAPI/Test.svc`. So far so good. But, when I place the same service under folder say 'Test1' and trying to access from the link `http://localhost/WOFAPI/Test.svc` throws 404. But when tried to access from the link `http://localhost/WOFAPI/Test1/Test.svc` it works ('Test1' is the name of the folder under which service is placed).

Service Behavior configuration as follows:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Service and Endpoint as follows:

```
<service name="Test" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
    <endpoint 
        address=""
        behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="ITest">
    </endpoint>
</service>
```

I also tried to place them in `App_Code` folder but no luck. Is it really possible to arrange them physically in folder and access without folder name? What am I missing?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able find solution for my question.

WCF, MVC and WebAPI rely on `System.Web.Routing` namespace for their routing activity. This namespace has a class `RouteTable`. This class has a member `Routes` of type `RouteCollection`. Add your service to this collection.

Follow below steps

1) Add `System.Web.Routes` dll to your project (My project was of type WCF application and there was no System.Web.Routes dll added by default)

2) Add `Global.asax` file

3) Add your service routes to `RoutesTable.Routes` collection from within `Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` function as shown below

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Test.svc", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Test)));
}
```

If you are using Niject WCF for Dependency Injection, follow below steps

1) Go to `Global.asax` (You may already be having `Global.asax` file which inherits `NinjectHttpApplication`)

2) Override `OnApplicationStarted()` function

3) Add route as shown below

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    base.OnApplicationStarted();
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Test.svc", new NinjectServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Test)));
}
```

On a side note, you can completely get rid of `.svc` extension for service if you would like to. Just don't add the extension in the Route Prefix. Instead of **"Test.svc"** just give **"Test"**. This will result in service without extension.

With extension -> `http://localhost/xyz/Test.svc`
Without extension -> `http://localhost/xyz/Test`

Comment: This is very useful, really appreciated for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure IIS to know where your svc file is.

Answer (score 0):

Change physical path for application in IIS

Comment: I hosted project in IIS. IIS properly finds services from root folder but not within sub folder. What is the reason for changing physical path. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This is because your physical path given in IIS contains only root folder so if .svc file is present in root folder then service will run but if you change your service location inside sub folder you should also change physical path in IIS because IIS will not be able to find .svc file (or dll) in the given physical path so service will not get starts.